# Bootcamp - Your bootable USB drive could not be created

Tags: macos, bootcamp, usb, disk-utility, windows

I'm trying to install Windows with Bootcamp using my USB drive (16GB). I've downloaded the original ISO (Win 7 Home Premium 64 bit), but when I try to create the bootable USB I always get this message after a couple of minutes:

[image]

I've tried to downoad a different ISO of Windows 7 but I got the same message, seems like the problem is not of the iso file. I run Yosemite 10.10.3. I've found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127885/bootcamp-bootable-usb-cannot-be-created) which is the exactly same problem, but the user didn't provided the solution that worked for him...

Comment: Where did you download the ISO image from and did you validate the downloaded file against any published checksum?

Comment: Nope I downloaded it from a site claiming to be the original untouched iso from Digital River in my language.